# SevenZipSharp Compression rate too low

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, compression, 7zip

I'm searching for days for a compression method that can possibly reduce the size by at least 50%, unfortunately i can't find one...

I've used the .net one's, GzipStream and DeflateStream but they're compression rates are just bad.
Then i found 7-zip, specifically [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)

So, i downloaded 7-zip (the actual program), specified the 7z.dll as the Library used by SevenZipSharp and used it like this:

This is for a client-server application.

```
 Private Shared Function SevenZip_Compress(ms As MemoryStream) As Byte()
    Using compressedstream As New MemoryStream

        Dim compressor As New SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor
        compressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma2
        compressor.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Ultra

        compressor.CompressStream(ms, compressedstream)
        ms.Dispose()
        Return compressedstream.ToArray
    End Using

End Function
```

Using this the compressedstream gets compressed from 131000~ to 103000~ bytes, which is still too high to send over the internet, and we're talking about in CompressionLevel.Ultra, if i put Low, the compression only gets reduced to 125000~. why is the compression rate so low?

I'm compressing Jpeg Images with a resolution of 1280x720.
I know Jpeg is already compressed, but if i used Png the original stream is 262000 and the compressed stream is like 350000 bytes (i can't understand why) so i sticked with Jpeg.
I'm creating the images at run-time, there's no disk-file involved if that matters.

To decompress the stream on the client side i'm using this:

```
  Private Function SevenZip_Decompress(bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim compressedstream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        Dim decompressor As New SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(compressedstream)
        Using decompressedstream As New MemoryStream
            decompressor.ExtractFile(0, decompressedstream)
            compressedstream.Dispose()
            Return decompressedstream.ToArray
        End Using
    End Function
```

I also tried using the "Shared" methods this library provides like this:

```
Dim bytes() =  SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.CompressBytes(ms.ToArray)
```

And to extract:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.ExtractBytes(bytes)
```

This works somewhat better, it compresses the same stream to 50000~ which is a 65% compression rate, which is quite good, (though i still wanted more..) but it uses 12% CPU for each image, which is too high, while the first method, whether is in Low or in Ultra only used 3% maximum CPU, which is acceptable.

The cpu is an i7-3610QM 2.3ghz.

This results we're made in a remote desktop session between server and client with 9 frames per second, i'm not using the remote desktop protocol, i'm sending 9 full-screenshots per second with that results.

So, i ask, is there anyother compression method better than SevenZipSharp library capabilities ?
If not, what can i do to reduce the image bytes sent so i don't need to burn my upload bandwith only on this? Is there a better way without using remote desktop protocol?

Comment: If you're worried about burning bandwidth, RDP is NOT going to help!

Comment: if you are creating/capturing the images, your best bet may be to use the ImageEncoder and reduce the jpg quality.  Each 5% increment in compression can result in a fair amount of size reduction.  You could also experiment with keeping the quality high, but reduce the size to 50% or 75% then resize to original on the other side.

Comment: jpeg images are already compressed so are hard to compress further using gzip etc., as @Plutonix points out by reducing quality or image resolution. Another option is to use an alternative image compression format, for example [JPEG 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000#Superior_compression_performance)

Comment: @Grim I thought it only sends the changed part of the screen instead a whole-screenshot like i'm doing and that would save bandwith... (never worked with it), @ Plutonix You mean it like [http://pastebin.com/wtkkWgKW](this?) I had tried it already, but i've tested it again, and it reduces the same image to 30kb, which is fantastic, i wanted a little bit less still but this is fairly good, @ Phillip Trelford, have you used that personally, can you tell me if it's easy to work with that in c#?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought you were trying to find a way to send 'an image' using as little bandwidth as possible; my comment was pointing out that RDP will use more bandwidth than ONE image (obviously!).  If you've got the tools to monitor your bandwidth, I'd be interested to know how much bandwidth a standard RDP session uses up...

Comment: I didn't know that, i only have one computer available right now, but you have the tools to check for bandwith too, (unless you're using Win XP...) go to Task manager, performance tab, and click Resource monitor (perfmon.exe) go to "Network" tab, and you're set.

I'm trying to workout with EncoderParameters, reducing the original size as much as i can to try and get the best quality for the least bandwith possible, wish me luck :p

Answer (score 1):

You can't compress already compressed stuff hardly at all, as you have discovered.  Your only option is to decode the JPEG images and recode them using a more effective image compression technique.  You could look at [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/).

Comment: Have you used that personally? Is it good for sending over the internet (small file-size?)

Comment: I have experimented with it.  Did you look at the link?  It's purpose in life is for sending images over the internet.

Comment: I did look at it, for now i've arranged something "quality-bandwith-stable" with EncoderParameters .net and then compressing with 7-zip as i was doing, it performs quite good, 9% Cpu with 10 frames p/sec, i've been messing with resolutions too and i was able to keep the original, which is 1920x1080 at 49kb per image, which is not that small but i'm keeping the original resolution and for now it's quite good, thanks for that, i'll bookmark this.